# Pictures directory-path Access-Denied using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I use the Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Shutter() Method to take a photo.
This Method fires an MediaCaptured-Event when the image is ready to grap.

The Photo apears in the Pictures Directory of the Android-Emulator, but i can't access the file.
I always get a "Acces-Denied"-Exception.

Here is the **first** try:

```
private async void MediaCaptured(object sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the aquired image
            imgView.Source = e.Image;
            
            //Show the image at the view 
            imgViewPanel.IsVisible = true;

            // The Byte-Array of the photo
            var photo = e.ImageData;
            var filename = "photo_test_01.png";
            var filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/" + filename;

            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, photo);

        }
```

The filepath is hardcoded.
In a different class, i use this Method to read the image:
`"File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, photo);"`
Here, i always get the "Acces-Denied" Exeption when i try to read the image.

This is why i tried different filePath variables, just to check wether this particular path is the problem or not -->

The **second** try:
I replaced the hardcoded filePath with this:
`var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);` 
But when i use this Xamarin.Essentials API, i can not find the file in the emulator.
There is even no "files" folder in the `/Android/data/learningXamarin/` folder, only "cache".
[AppDataDirectory of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m23ci.png)

And **many other** tries:
I also tried this file-paht:

`var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), filename);`

Everything without success

Here is my AndroidManifest:
[AndroidManifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8KSx.png)

And i use the Pixel5- Android11 (API30) Emulator

Comment: `i use this Method to read the image: "File.WriteAllBytes...`? Read ? Or Write?

Comment: Use File.exists() and File.canRead() before accessing the file.

Comment: You can’t just read/write the system photos folder

Comment: Read current docs about access to media files on Android.

Comment: Is this image file created by your app?

Comment: Yes it is created by the app

Comment: Did you want to upload your app to the goolge play store? If not, you can try to get the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.